# Can select2 `id` properties be strings which look like objects

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

For select2 the `id` [properties must be **Strings**](https://select2.github.io/options.html#do-the-id-properties-have-to-be-strings). Which is all well and good, But I was hoping to have have an id that is still a string but looks like an object:

```
{ 'name': 'foo','text': 'bar', 'id': '{"looks": "like an object"}' }
```

But when the select2 menu renders with the `id` being value `[object Object]`. If i change the `name` or the `text` value to a `'{"String": "which looks like an object"}'` I get the same `[object Object]`.

Is there a workaround? Is there a way to use select2 to display a string which looks like an object?

Comment: It is a little complicated to describe the UI's intention in SO, but basically the user will be filling out a form which constructs an object which will be in the body of an API request. The UI is intended to be pedagogical so I would like them to understand that by selecting this option they will be setting these fields to these values.

My turn... why do you ask?

Comment: I'm just confused. I couldn't really see a reason to do such a thing...